# how to mount encrypted drive over ssh, using password stored on local machine

Tags: ssh

I have two computers in my possesion, one local, one remote. The remote machine I have full access too (root), but it is not really in a physically secure location (i.e. someone can break into the office and steal the drives).

I use the remote machine for storing encrypted backups... first I mount the encrypted partition, then I run my backup (rsync), then I unmount the partition; in this way I can be assured that if the remote machine is stolen then my stuff is still secure.

However, this backup process is a 3 stage process (mount, rsync, unmount), I want to automate it so that it's all 1 script that I have to execute.

The problem is that I don't know how to provide my password (that I type in when the script executes in my local machine) from my local machine to the remote server so that it can mount the encrypted partition.

Is there any way I can provide my password to the remote server, either by typing it in while the script executes or while reading from a file on my local disk somewhere?

Otherwise, anyother tips or suggestions that might do the trick instead?

Edit: I should add that the mounting and unmounting steps are currently run on the remote server, but the rsync process runs on my local machine. I basically rsync a directory from local to remote.

Comment: Is the password to connect to the remote machine, or is it to decrypt the partition?

Comment: The password is needed to mount the encrypted partition on the remote server. I am using ssh with passwordless authentication, and password logins disabled.

Comment: Could you post your script so we can see the commands being used? How are you mounting the drive? Is this over NFS? What operating system are you using? Unix? Linux? OSX? Windows?

Comment: It's not really a script (I described that badly)... it's just a 1-liner rsync command; I put it into a bash script so that I don't need to remember all the details of the command. Before running that rsync "script", I ssh into the remote box and mount the drive (encrfs). I logout, run the rsync script, then when done I log back in and unmount the drive. Both machines are running linux.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this is with an automation tool like [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm); there's also a similar Python-based tool called [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/).

If you're not comfortable with conventional programming, there's an interesting visual automation tool called [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) that should also work for this purpose.